# How to set a default language for the virtual keyboard of an EditText

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-virtual-keyboard

I'm wanted to know if there any way i could set the default language of the virtual keyboard of an `EditText` in `Android`?

Every time i get focus on my `EditText` it opens the virtual keyboard with my native language instead of English.

I guess it something with the device settings, but if there is a way to program that in `Android` development that would be terrific.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android]  Maybe this could help you.

Comment: @user2690455 Thank you. could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocaleHelper`” is the solution all you need. You just have to initialize locale on your application’s main class. After that all your language changes will persist.

In application class make following changes:

```
    public class MainApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        LocaleHelper.onCreate(this, "en");
    }
}
```

LocalHelper.java will be:

```
public class LocaleHelper {

private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

public static void onCreate(Context context) {
    String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    setLocale(context, lang);
}

public static void onCreate(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
    String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
    setLocale(context, lang);
}

public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
    return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
}

public static void setLocale(Context context, String language) {
    persist(context, language);
    updateResources(context, language);
}

private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
}

private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
    editor.apply();
}

private static void updateResources(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;

    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

}

For detail description you refer [this](http://gunhansancar.com/change-language-programmatically-in-android/) link.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, But i don't have any `Application` class.

Comment: Then you need to create a class which will extend `Application`. Follow the instructions from link.

Comment: I will. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it compulsory to extend `Application` class ? We can pass getApplicationContext() to `LocaleHelper.onCreate(getApplicationContext(), "en");`  right ?

Comment: yes, because by extending `Application` it will make `onCreate` method available to the rest of your application components

Comment: This sets the language for the entire app. What if I want to to set ONLY an editext so the remaining app can remain in the device's locale

Comment: for multiple edittext's with different input languages, this is not a  solution!

Comment: This is not a solution, because it doesn't answer the original question. The question is about changing language for virtual keyboard, and the answer contains info about changing app locale.

Comment: Not recommend if you only want change language in keyboard